# Amount of repeating numbers in a special sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series

Suggest we have the sequence of sequences that is constructed according to these rules:

1. First sequence is filled with 1.
2. Second sequence copies the first one, but puts 2 into every position that is a multiple of 2.
3. Third sequence copies the second one, but puts 3 into every position that is a multiple of 3.
4. (...)

```
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
1 2 1 2 1 2 1 2 1 2
1 2 3 2 1 3 1 2 3 2
1 2 3 4 1 3 1 4 3 2
1 2 3 4 5 3 1 4 3 5
```

Does this sequence has special name? Are there any formulas to estimate the count of number `M` in `i`-th sequence of length `N`?

For example:

```
func count(M int, i int, length int) int { //... }

count(1, 1, 10) == 10
count(1, 2, 10) == 5
count(1, 3, 10) == 3
count(5, 1, 10) == 0
count(5, 5, 10) == 2
```

Comment: Wouldn't count on it having a name, as OEIS doesn't seem to give me anything. As for what this is, the $n$th element of the $m$th sequence is simply the largest factor of $n$ that is less than $m$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no simple formula for `count(1, i, length)`.

## Reduction to known task

### Observation 1

The process described is the well known Sieve of Eratosphenes algorithm for prime numbers lookup, where we have 1-s on places what belong to prime numbers. And we have these facts:

- There's always 1 at the first column
- Numbers on columns 2…M-1 on (M-1)-th row are not 1-s.
- Number on M-th column of (M-1)-th row is equal to 1 then and only then when M is a prime number.

### Observation 2

Amount of 1-s within the first M-th cells of the M-1 row is equal to

```
U(M) = count(1, M-1, M) - count(1, M-2, M)
```

if `count` is a cheap to compute formula then `U` is cheap too.

### Consequence

`U(M)` equals 2 if M is prime and 1 if M is not prime.

So, and the original `count` for 1 is not cheaper than `U` and that is not particularly cheap. I mean, `U(M)` shows if M is either prime or not. This is not cheap.